# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - November 14, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (EST):** November 14, 2018, 6:30 p.m.

**Date/Time (UTC):** November 14, 2018, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/255665631/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on November 14th, at 6:30 p.m., at [Roam in Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us)!

We are very proud of our Atlanta community members who represented us very well at Sitecore Symposium this year. At this meeting, we are going to have a collection of short lightning talks showcasing several of our local speaker sessions.

Talks will cover a wide range of topics from JSS, Marketing Automation, Machine Learning, Commerce, and more.

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served.

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 6:45: Food, drinks, and social time
- 6:45 - 7:05: [Anastasiya Flynn](https://twitter.com/AnastasiyaFlynn) ([Arke](https://www.arke.com/)) - Take Your Sitecore Project to the Next Level with Node.js
- 7:10 - 7:30: [Sam Sabel](https://www.linkedin.com/in/samuelsabel/) ([Rightpoint](https://www.rightpoint.com/)) - Igniting Your Commerce Experience
- 7:35 - 7:55: [Steve Ebrahimi](https://www.linkedin.com/in/steven-ebrahimi/) ([Avanade](https://www.avanade.com/en)) - Accessibility in Sitecore: Managing an Inclusive Digital Experience
- 8:00 - 8:20: [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) & [Rick Bauer](https://twitter.com/sitecordial) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/)) - Working with JSS Gold Master and Marketing Automation
- 8:20: Closing comments, end of event